# sequelize.js how can I reconnect after close

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, sequelize.js

I use the sequelize.js to connect sqlite, but I must to close the connect because I want to modify the sqlite's file. Windows cannot modify the file when it's opening.

I create the object like this:

```js
const sequelize = new Sequelize('database', null, null, {
    dialect: 'sqlite',
    storage: 'db.sql',
    define: {
      timestamps: false,
      freezeTableName: true
    },
    dialectModule: sqlite3
  })
```

And when I close the connect, I cannot reconnect sqlite by the original object.
I try to use the ConnectionManager initPools, but it does not work.

```js
sequelize.close()
// do something ...
sequelize.connectionManager.initPools()
sequelize.authenticate() // raise the error by disconnect
```

Comment: this is no possible in v6 https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/getting-started/#closing-the-connection (see note). you will need to make a new instance.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for necroposting.

I think, I've found a workaround.

1. Wrap your db handler in class

`// DBHandler.ts
class DBHandler {

  public dbInstance: Sequelize | undefined = undefined;

  constructor(
    readonly dbConf: Options,
  ) {}

  async connect() {
    // Check if the Sequelize instance already exist
    if (this.dbInstance)
      throw new ApplicationError('Database connection is already initialized');

    // Connection is created here
    this.dbInstance = new Sequelize(
      DATABASE_URL,
      this.dbConf
    );
    
    // Private method listed below
    await this.initModels();
  }

  async initModels() {
    
    // Init each model via functions - see the next code block
    await initFooModel(this.dbInstance);
    // ... other models

    // Init associations and hooks if you have any -
    // make sure to do it after all the models init
    await initAssociations();
    await initHooks();
  }

  async close() {
    // Check if sequelize instance exists
    if (!this.dbInstance)
      throw new ApplicationError('Database connection is not initialized');

    await this.dbInstance.close();
  }

}`

2. Model definition files, assuming usage of Model.init() (will also work with .define()): wrap Model.init(...args) in Promise, then wrap it in an async function

`// Foo.ts

export const initFooModel = async (dbInstance: Sequelize) => {
  return new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
    try {

      // Your actual Model.init()
      Foo.init({
        id: {
          type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
          primaryKey: true,
          autoIncrement: true
        },
        bar: {
          type: DataTypes.STRING(5000),
          allowNull: false
        },
        baz: {
          type: DataTypes.STRING(9001),
          allowNull: true
        },
      }, {
        // Sequelize property in options === Sequelize instance
        sequelize: dbInstance,
        ... // other options
      });

      resolve();
    } catch(e) {
      reject(e)
    }
  });
};`

3. Do the same with associations:

`// initModelAssociations.ts

export const initModelAssociations = async () => {
  return new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
    try {

      // Your actual associations declaration here
      Foo.belongsTo(Bar);
      ...

      resolve();
    } catch(e) {
      reject(e);
    }
  });
};`

4. Do the same wrap with hooks.

I've tested this with PostgreSQL, but I think it should work with SQLite too.
There is no need to make those functions asynchronous, if you prefer synchronous init, just remove those Promises.

Further in your code:

`const dbHandler = new DBHandler(
  // Your Sequelize config here
)

await dbHandler.connect();
...
await dbHandler.close();
...
await dbHandler.connect();`

Should work!

// Sorry, could not format (1.) properly